# Client is loosing some lines from TCP socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, stream, newline

My `ServerSocket` writes out the following lines:

```
OutputStreamWriter outstream = new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(outstream);

out.write("Hello");
out.newLine();
out.write("People");

out.flush();
```

And my client reads it like so:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
while(true){
    line = in.readLine();

    if(line == null){
        ClientDialog.gui.log.append("NULL LINE\r\n");
    } else{
        ClientDialog.gui.log.append(line+"\r\n");
    }

    if(in.readLine() == "SHUTDOWN"){
        break;
    }
}
```

As you can see I write "Hello", a new line, and then "People" on the socket, but when I run my client, it only prints "Hello" and null repeatedly. I don't see what is wrong?

---

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

I had to add an `out.newLine()` after I wrote "People" to the socket, and I had to do `line == "SHUTDOWN"` not `in.readLine() == "SHUTDOWN"` as the `in.readLine()` was consuming "People".

It was also recommended to use the `equals()` method in the `String` class, instead of `==`.

Thanks!

*This is for future viewers.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You call readLine twice per loop.

```
if(in.readLine() == "SHUTDOWN"){
        break;
}
```

The code above consumes your "People" line

to fix change to

```
if("SHUTDOWN".equals(line){
            break;
}
```

Also you should send a newline after sending "People"

Comment: Ah, that did the trick. I'm just finally starting to get serious about programming. Thanks for that. :D

Comment: @Ken Important to note as well is that you should not compare String objects using '==' operator. Use the Object.equals(Object) method as I demonstrated above.

Comment: @Ken If you do `line.equals("SHUTDOWN")` and `line` is null you will get a `NullPointerException`. Whereas if you do it the way I demonstrated above then if `line` is null the expression will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Oh! That makes sense once you say that. :D

Answer (score 3):

This

```
    if(in.readLine() == "SHUTDOWN")
    {
        break;
    }
```

Should be this:

```
    if(line == "SHUTDOWN")
    {
        break;
    }
```

You are calling `readLine()` twice and thus consuming one of your lines

Also, when comparing String types, you should use the `equals()` method in the String class:

```
    if(line != null && line.equals("SHUTDOWN"))
    {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: well, it really should be `line != null && line.equals("SHUTDOWN")` or `"SHUTDOWN".equals(line)`...

Comment: @GregHewgill The OP tests for a null string already in the first if block

Comment: and if it's null, then what happens?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. You are right but `null == "SHUTDOWN"` will return false always. But the equals call will cause an error. editing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that your `in.readLine() == "SHUTDOWN"` is consuming the "people" in the stream. Further `==` won't work either.

Comment: and fix the "== "SHUTDOWN" thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send another newline after you send people. Your call to readLine is waiting for that to signal it to process more data.

Try

```
out.write("Hello");
out.newLine();
out.write("People")
out.newLine();
```